# Свои список файлов при создание файла (PHPStorm)?

Tags: php, phpstorm

`File` > `New...` > показывается список. Где его отредактировать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: под отредактировать вы что понимаете? удалить/сортировать, либо добавить новый тип файлов с шаблоном для создания?

Comment: Необходимо отредактировать сам список, типы файлов и их порядок...

Comment: `Settings` > `Menus and Toolbars` > `Navigation bar` > `New`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Товарищ @teran подсказал верный ответ. Т.к. путь до необходимых настроек у меня отличается, то напишу свой:

`Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `Menus and Toolbars` > `Navigation Bar` > `New`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: такой же у вас путь, я просто пропустил пункт :)

Answer (score 4):

В настройках IDE: Preferences->Editor->File and code Templates.

[image: PHPStorm Settings]

Comment: Не то, он не редактирует список типов файлов и их порядок на моем скрине...

Comment: @MikeRo вот пример: я добавил тестовый темплейт, он появился в списке, когда создаешь новый файл: http://joxi.ru/ZrJ3QJh9LZqemj

Comment: Добавил .scss файл http://take.ms/wwOgO , у меня не появился http://take.ms/f4VY8

Comment: @MikeRo, "SCSS File" в списке по умолчанию. Попробуйте добавить новый, например, с именем "SCSS" и соответствующее расширение

Comment: Действительно, файл добавился. Но как отредактировать всю панель с этими файлами? Поменять местами и убрать не нужные?
`Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars > Navigation Bar > New` - здесь можно менять местами, но я так и не понял, как добавить туда свой файл, например php